# How I create a regular expression to find lines of code that contain cflocation but do not contain addtoken?

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will find lines with:

```
<cflocation url="index.cfm" addtoken="No">
```

but without the addtoken

```
<cflocation url="index.cfm">
```

The index.cfm can be any web address

I also added a comment below but this is for my text editor so I can search in files for all cflocation tags that are missing addtoken.

Thanks!

Comment: We need more to this question.

Comment: Why it is a regular expression question not a coldfusion question.   I want to use a regular expression in my text editor that finds  lines in a file that have cflocation in the line but does not have addtoken.  Is another category more appropriate?

Comment: That's why it's a regex question; you want to search text with an expression, but this text just happens to be CF code.

Comment: I am trying to figure out why my question was marked down. It is a regular expression question and I used CF code in my explanation because that is the content I am searching for inside the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<cflocation\s+url="[^"]*"\s*>`

You can test out regex's with data at [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com).
You can use [strfriend.com](http://www.strfriend.com/vis?re=%3Ccflocation%5Cs%2burl=%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%5Cs*%3E) to explain regex's, an example output for the regex above is given below:
[image]

Comment: I will play around with this some.  The first run through editplus did not match any entries.

Comment: I took out the first \s and it worked:  <cflocation url="[^"]*"\s*>